# sqrt - Advices to ameliorate spacing

Tags: math-operators

I do not like the spacing printed by sqrt. In the following code, which not takes care of empty optional argument for the moment, I break the good spacing before the sqrt symbol.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\let\stdsqrt\sqrt
\renewcommand\sqrt[2][]{\stdsqrt[#1\,\,]{#2\,}}


\begin{document}

Bla, bla $\sqrt{2} = \stdsqrt{2}$ et $\sqrt[2]{3} = \stdsqrt[2]{3}$ .

Bla, bla $\stdsqrt{2} = \sqrt{2}$ et $\stdsqrt[2]{3} = \sqrt[2]{3}$ .

\end{document}
```

Comment: Might be an idea to include an image as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're better using `\leftroot`:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Bla, bla $\sqrt{2} = \sqrt{2}$ et $\sqrt[\leftroot{1}3]{3} = \sqrt[3]{3}$.

Bla, bla $\sqrt{2} = \sqrt{2}$ et $\sqrt[\leftroot{3}3]{3} = \sqrt[3]{3}$.

Bla, bla $\sqrt{2} = \sqrt{2}$ et $\sqrt[3\,\,]{3} = \sqrt[3]{3}$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

I've never seen the index just above the left margin of the radical.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to `\leftroot` such as to not have no more problem with `\sqrt` left unsolved.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the problem comes from the missing treatment of the first empty argument. The following code seems to do the job.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\let\stdsqrt\sqrt
\renewcommand\sqrt[2][]{\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\stdsqrt{#2\,}\else\stdsqrt[\!\!#1\,\,]{#2\,}\fi}


\begin{document}

Bla, bla $\sqrt{2} = \stdsqrt{2}$ et $\sqrt[2]{3} = \stdsqrt[2]{3}$ .

Bla, bla $\stdsqrt{2} = \sqrt{2}$ et $\stdsqrt[2]{3} = \sqrt[2]{3}$ .

\end{document}
```